# Targeting window.location.pathname in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

How can I target window.location.pathname in NEXT.JS?

I have this code and next.js shows me nice red err

```
export const isAdmin = window.location.pathname.startsWith("/adminpath");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it with this code:

```
'use client';

import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation';


export default function isAdmin() {
  return usePathname().startsWith('/adminpath');
}
```